# How to kill terminal processes left open?

Tags: docker, portainer

I'm using Portainer to connect to my container's terminal but sometimes I forget to `exit` and change page or close browser. The process list will growing until I stop the container and start it again. In the image below you can see a `sh` and a `tail` left running and the normal `java` from the entrypoint.

Is there some way to kill these processes (not the CMD of corse)? Already tried to `kill -9` from inside the container but they say the PID cannot be found.

[image]

Comment: Could be related to this bug report: https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/665

Comment: So... nothing we can do.